# Where is the code of rails doing rendering and layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing

I am working on a project which involves understanding the mechanism of how rails does rendering and layouts, including, where does rails know that it needs to do rendering (either by a render statement or default rendering), which view file it is going to render, how is view file nested together, how does rails merge the layouts with the view file, how does rails decide which layout file to use for a specific render statement. I hope there are some existing code module I can use to produce such rendering results, so I don't have to write code to mimic this process myself.

Comment: Your question has too many sub-questions. Please reduce it to one or two closely related questions. [ask]. Stack Overflow isn't a good site to ask a "how does this work" question for something as broad and complex as Rails. We have no idea what your level of experience is, so any usable answers will have to start at the CIS 101 level and move upward, which is too broad and off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Backing what the Tin Man said, I'm gonna do my best to answer this as 'How does rendering views work'

First you create a controller....

```
rails g controller welcome index
```

This creates the `welcome controller` with the action `index`

By action, I mean if you look inside the new welcome controller you will see

```
def index
end
```

That's where all the variables and stuff go that you need inside of that 'page' for example if you need to print out all the users, you would do this

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

Now, inside of /config/routes.rb, when you typed in `rails g controller welcome index` it generated a route something like this

```
get '/welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'
```

What that does, is when someone goes to the URL `http://localhost:3000/welcome/index` Rails will point to the `welcome controller` and render the `index action`

What that will do is tell rails, 'HEY, theres an action called index, go look in /views/welcome and make sure there's a file called `index.html.erb`

That WILL be there because when you generated the controller, it generates the views for the actions you specify, in this case we only specified `index`.

Now Rails knows what controller to look in and what action and html to render.

That's pretty much the basics :)

Hope this helps!